# Converting hash into multiline argument in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, cucumber

Hi I am calling a step in another step and both the steps uses table as argument. My issue is when I am in step 1 I am converting the table in to hash and accessing the values from it. Now my issue is I want to pass the same hash or current row values to the step called in it. How should I do it? Format of the table in feature file and code is as below:

Table I have to pass or atleast the rows I am interested in:

```
   |column_a|column_b|column_c|
   |1       |2       |3       |
   |4       |2       |6       |
   |3       |1       |7       |  

And(/^I verify the structure$/) do |table|
  hashes = table.hashes
  hashes.each do |deeplink_url|
    if deeplink_url['column_b'] == '2'
    step('I verify that following transactions are reported', table)
  end
end
```

The table I am passing is the same table used in the step it self. My idea is to pass the current row:

```
step('I verify that following transactions are reported', deeplink_url['column_b','column_c'])
```

But the above line gives an error that it is not multiline argument.
Is there a way to convert the hash back to table or pass that particular row only from the table?

Comment: This may just be me, but I'm not finding this too clear - could you expand with example input, what you've tried and desired output please?

Comment: @SRack I do not want to pass the whole table just the few selected rows. how can I do this?

Comment: are you trying to connvert the hash back to table-formatted string? Can you try passing in that value manually, to see if it works first?

Comment: @max pleaner no it does not work and yes I would love to convert the hash back to table

Comment: So, if you tried manually entering in the table value and it didn't work, why do you want to do it? Can show your attempt to manually pass in the table string?

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest steps you are just asking for trouble. Instead extract a helper method and call that instead. This will make passing parameters much simpler. So in your code you can replace

`step('I verify that following transactions are reported', table)`

with

`verify_table(...)`

This gives you much greater control over the params and how you process them, and makes the call much simpler.

Nesting steps is a cucumber anti-pattern.